# How to generate get result from DB when range is provided for searching String column in database?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have requirement of getting data from database having column as below:

```
id int(11) PK 
quarter varchar(45) 
year int(11)
```

Quarter can take value of yearly quarter as String e.x. `Q1` , `Q2` , `Q3`, `Q4`.
Year can take value from 2011 to 2014.

Requirement:

- User will input range i.e. for Quarter as Q1 and Q3
- User will inout range i.e. for Year as 2011 and 2013.

We have to return the data that is for Quarter in Q1, Q2, Q3 and Year in 2011,2012 and 2013 and ignore others. Likewise user can input any range.

Please help suggest how can I build generic SQL query for getting the result set?

Comment: Please show your query as is.

Comment: select * from table
where year between 2011 AND 2014
AND Quarter <> 'Q4'

This will give the output but this is not generic one i.e. if user changes the range then search criteria needs to change to in order to accomodate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the alphabetic order of the quarter coincides with the chronological one, you might as well use:

SELECT *
FROM   your_table
WHERE  quarter BETWEEN :Qfrom AND :Qto
  AND  year BETWEEN :Yfrom AND :Yto

Where Qfrom, Qto, Yfrom and Yto are the parameters provided by the user

Comment: We can use 'BETWEEN' only for YEAR since it is an integer and iterate from one value to other, but for String value i.e. 'Q1', 'Q2' we cant since it is a String.

Comment: I don't know what DB you use, but within Oracle it's possible. Otherwise you might try WHERE Quarter >= :Qfrom AND Quarter <= :Qto AND Year BETWEEN :Yfrom AND :Yto

Comment: Thanks a ton kockie.. It worked :) I am working on mySQL right now and fired query as :

SELECT * 
FROM table ct
where ct.year between YFrom AND Yto
AND ct.quarter between QFrom AND QTo;

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM YOURTABLE
WHERE CONCAT(CAST(YEAR AS VARCHAR), QUARTER) IN (:QuarterList)
```

Then supply a list to the parameter in the form '2014Q1', '2014Q2' ...